# I cannot login via SSH to Compute Engine instance hosting Ubuntu 20 LTS image

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-compute-engine

I have been dealing with this error since yesterday. I cannot ssh into my instance and solve anything. Also, I cannot log in via Serial port. I feel a little bit lost with this error.

I tried resizing the instance's disk, but it did not work.
I also tried to create a user and a password via startup-script, but it did not work.
Also, I can see that the snapshot is only 3.5GB and my disk size is 10GB so the "No space left on device" log does not make a lot of sense to me.

Any help would be quite appreciated.

My serial logs are:

```
Oct  8 21:58:26 mudii-back systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.
Oct  8 21:58:27 mudii-back systemd-networkd[464]: Could not set hostname: Method call timed out
Oct  8 21:58:28 mudii-back dbus-daemon[480]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service' requested by ':1.3' (uid=0 pid=504 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/un" label="unconfined")
Oct  8 21:58:28 mudii-back systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
Oct  8 21:58:28 mudii-back systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No space left on device
Oct  8 21:58:28 mudii-back systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Oct  8 21:58:28 mudii-back systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
Oct  8 21:58:28 mudii-back systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Oct  8 21:58:28 mudii-back systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
```

Some more logs:

```
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back systemd[1]: google-instance-setup.service: Succeeded.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back systemd[1]: Finished Google Compute Engine Instance Setup.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back systemd[1]: ssh.service: Succeeded.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Instance Setup...
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO Running google_set_multiqueue.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO Set channels for ens4 to 2.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO Setting /proc/irq/31/smp_affinity_list to 0 for device virtio1.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO /proc/irq/31/smp_affinity_list: real affinity 0
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO Setting /proc/irq/32/smp_affinity_list to 0 for device virtio1.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO /proc/irq/32/smp_affinity_list: real affinity 0
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO Setting /proc/irq/33/smp_affinity_list to 1 for device virtio1.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO /proc/irq/33/smp_affinity_list: real affinity 1
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO Setting /proc/irq/34/smp_affinity_list to 1 for device virtio1.
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO /proc/irq/34/smp_affinity_list: real affinity 1
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO Queue 0 XPS=1 for /sys/class/net/ens4/queues/tx-0/xps_cpus
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: INFO Queue 1 XPS=2 for /sys/class/net/ens4/queues/tx-1/xps_cpus
Oct  9 00:52:47 mudii-back instance-setup: WARNING [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

John Hanley's answer worked for me. The step that I needed to add was to create another instance with the same system image (Ubuntu in my case) and resizing the partition from there.

Answer (score 2):

Your system is out of disk space. In most cases resizing the disk is very easy. In some rare cases, the root file system will need repair.

Go to the Google Cloud [Console GUI](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) for Compute Engine.

Select your virtual machine instance and click **STOP**. Wait for the shutdown to complete.

Click on the instance name. Scroll down to the section **Boot disk**. Click on the boot disk name.

You will now be on a screen "Manage disk".

Note: as a safety measure, snapshot the boot disk. There is a link near the top **CREATE SNAPSHOT**. You can also clone the disk.

Click the **EDIT** link near the top.

Under **Properties** enter a new disk size. Add 10 GB or larger to the existing size. Click SAVE.

Restart the VM instance. The system will automatically resize the disk.

I wrote an article that discusses this issue and how to do everything using the CLI. The steps are the same for Ubuntu.

[Google Cloud – Debian 9 – Resize Root File System](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and answer but I still cannot conect via ssh to my VM.

Comment: @PedroDavidPérezDelfín - Update your question with the new serial logs.

Comment: I have some more logs but the thing is that when I resize de disk in ubuntu it does not resize automatically it seems.

Comment: I added more logs

Comment: @PedroDavidPérezDelfín - In my article I show how the system resizes. Resize the disk again and then review the logs that show the resize occurring. Verify that the resize is happening. You might have a file system error which means you need to run fsck which means mounting the disk on another identical OS and running fsck. I do not know how experienced you are, remember details matter in getting good advice.

Comment: I'm not really experianced, can you share an article that explains how to run fsck. I will also search for more information.

Comment: This level of work requires good skills. I wrote another article that shows how to recover from UFW lockout. Method #3 shows you how to mount the boot disk on another instance. Then run **fsck** with the file system device name as the command line argument. Example **fsck /dev/sdb1** https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/ Here is a link to an article on running fsck to repair a file system: https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/

Comment: Hi again. I followed the article and I have this log after running "fsck":  

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdb

Comment: Man at the end I managed to resize the disk on another instance. Thanks for the patience, I don´t have the reputation for voting your answer right now but I will when I do so. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an article on how to resize the disk automatically?

Comment: The article link in my answer. That article goes over the process in detail.

Comment: @PedroDavidPérezDelfín Does this answer helped you? If yes please accept.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script as a startup script [1] inside your vm. Afterwards enable the serial console and start the VM. You can go ahead and login using these credentials: Username (caleston) and pass (caleston123).

In order to login to the serial console, when its opens press once "enter" and you should be able to see “login”, afterwards you can paste the credentials and you have access in order to further troubleshoot.

---

[1]:

```
#! /bin/bash
adduser caleston
echo 'caleston:caleston123' | chpasswd
usermod -aG google-sudoers caleston
```