# Increasing Docker container disk space limit on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running docker on GCP's container optimized os (through a VM). Is there any way to increase docker container disk space limitation?

Here is the results of `uname -a`

`Linux instance-1 4.19.197+ #1 SMP Thu Jul 22 21:10:38 PDT 2021 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.80GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`

Due to lack of permission I could not implement previous solutions on SO.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Google Cloud does not have a space limitation for containers.

Comment: Make the disk for your VM larger.

Comment: Please see my answer here on how to resize a VM disk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69502752/8016720

Comment: @JohnHanley
Thanks, The problem is not the VM disk size per se. It has storage but it seems that there is a limitation for the containers' disk image size.

Comment: @Hitobat Please read above comment

Comment: Please state details. What limitation on size? How big is the container? What message is reported that indicates a limitation?

Comment: I deleted that VM instance let me recreate the problem and will update the post here. Thanks